# Validate if a string is valid JSONATA expression

Tags: javascript, npm, jsonata

Scenario:

1. User enters a JSONATA expression in to a form field.
2. Form should display an error if the entered JSONATA expression is invalid.

Is there a regex or pattern that can determine if a string is valid jsonata expression?

Expecting a regex or fucntion from npm package which validates whether the given string is valid jsonata expression or not

Comment: don't know the library, but shouldn't you be able to call `jsonata(myString)` and catch the error if parsing fails? [docs](https://docs.jsonata.org/embedding-extending#jsonatastr)

Comment: providing [mcve] of what you have/have tried would help. Also example input

Answer (score 2):

Creating a regex to determine if a string is a valid JSONata expression would be very complex and likely unreliable. JSONata expressions can be quite intricate, and trying to cover all the possible variations in a single regex pattern would be impractical.

Instead, the recommended approach would be to use the JSONata library to evaluate the expression and handle any exceptions that might occur. If an exception is thrown, you can assume that the entered JSONata expression is invalid.

Here's a simple example using JavaScript and the JSONata library:

```
const jsonata = require('jsonata');

function isValidJSONataExpression(expression) {
  try {
    jsonata(expression);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

// Usage example
const expression = 'your JSONata expression here';
if (isValidJSONataExpression(expression)) {
  console.log('The expression is valid');
} else {
  console.log('The expression is invalid');
}
```

This approach would provide a more accurate and maintainable way to check for the validity of a JSONata expression.

If you don't want to manage code and just want to try out some expressions, check out the [JSONata Playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground).